# Custom day, week, month resource views in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am interested to find out if it is possible to customize fullcalendar to do custom views of resource calendars for month, week and day views. The events displayed are only single all-day events. No multi-day events or time data.

The month plan is similar to the daily scheduler vertical resource view at [fullcalendar.com](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/demos/vertical-resource-view.html)

However, I need it for a month view with days as vertical rows.

I have not found any examples of the required day view or week view.
I have tried to adjust the settings and played around with it for a bit, but I haven't found out if this is possible.

I include some simple sketches of what I am looking for. I hope to get a few pointers if this is viable in fullcalendar or if I should look at another library.

[image: Month View]

[image: Week View]

[image: Day View]

Comment: Did you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js ? It's possible but certainly not simple. Maybe study the code of the built-in views (all the code is on GitHub) to see how they are written. Consider whether you really _need_ this view, or whether you could adapt the existing views a little bit more to your needs. Consider the info you need to communicate to the user and whether you could communicate the same thing with a different layout than your original sketches above. Making a custom view is a big effort and then requires maintenance afterwards to stay compatible.

Comment: P.S. Your second view ("weekly plan") would be achievable using a timeline view with custom duration and slotduration settings. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration/. And the 3rd ("Daily") is just a one-day vertical resource view (see demo on the right of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view).  Only the first example is problematic. But again if you used a timeline view with custom durations you'd get the same as that sketch but just rotated (people on the left column, dates at the top).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I did look at that customization page, but will have a look at your other links.

Comment: I have looked at these links earlier also and while somewhat helpful, they don't fully address my needs. I need the month calendar to have the days vertically as there are many more days than resources and there will not be enough width available to have days horizontal. Also, the calendars should only list all-day events, no time slots displayed. If someone has done any such customizations it would be much appreciated to have a look at it.

Comment: "there will not be enough width available to have days horizontal"...if you use the timeline view it will automatically add a scrollbar. Or you can show a smaller number of days at one time and let the user use the next/previous buttons to navigate them. It's a small usability issue but users would soon get used to it. See if you can live with it, because it's a small price to pay compared to the time, investment and ongoing maintenance commitment required to make a totally custom view and keep it up to date.

Comment: As for the timeslots, perhaps you didn't quite grasp that if you set the slotDuration to 1 day (or more), then the times will disappear, because you're simply setting the size of each slot to be a whole day rather than 30 minutes (or whatever). Obviously this will also considerably reduce the width required for displaying the data. Take a look at this demo to see a similar effect: https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/demos/scale.html (choose the "month" or "year" options on the right)